# What is the best way of converting a Html table to datatable

Tags: c#-3.0

I have  a html table.I want to convert this into a datatable. What is the best way of doing so? 
Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't parse the HTML yourself, there are parsing libraries out there that can do that for you.  Coupled with the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) and LINQ, you can make short work of this.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr");
var table = new DataTable("MyTable");

var headers = nodes[0]
    .Elements("th")
    .Select(th => th.InnerText.Trim());
foreach (var header in headers)
{
    table.Columns.Add(header);
}

var rows = nodes.Skip(1).Select(tr => tr
    .Elements("td")
    .Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim())
    .ToArray());
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Would this take care of colspans and table styling (css)?  This looks like it would simply translate the data and element markup

Comment: @user327999: no, this is just a one-to-one mapping. DataTables doesn't have such a thing anyway AFAIK.

Comment: I just downloaded HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6 in order to do this. The website says there is no documentation yet. I tried following the example here, but got a **NullReferenceException** at this: `var headers = nodes[0].Elements("th").Select(th => th.InnerText.Trim());` The **nodes** was `null`. How do I use this control? Where can I find current documentation on it?

Comment: @jp2code: It would depend on the markup you're parsing. The documentation is admittedly lacking, but most methods do have regular XML documentation which should be enough, the last time I've checked. But I believe it was modeled after `XmlDocument` and related classes so if you're familiar with parsing XML using the XML library, you should feel right at home. `nodes` is the result of calling `HtmlNode.SelectNodes()` which you pass in an xpath selector. Apparently no tables with immediate rows were found in your example.

Comment: I made some small adjustments to fit my table, but it worked perfectly .. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

...some years later...

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr");
```

line has a typo and needs to be with double forward slash after 'table' and everything works like a charm

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr");
```

Comment: This is not necessarily correct, at least, it would be wrong to classify it as a typo... and depending on the situation, probably wrong. Most people write tables where the `tr` elements are the direct children of the `table` node. (`<table><tr>...</tr></table>`) But a change like this might be needed if the rows were under a `tbody` element. It wouldn't be wrong if that were the case but I would say it's not as common. But this will have problems, especially when there are nested tables involved. But... that's purely situational... as is this case.